# EclipseLink JPA: How can I specify zeroDateTimeBehavior=converToNull

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I need to set the zeroDateTimeBehavior property to convertToNull in my EclipseLink configuration. I am using a properties file where I am using javax.persistence.jdbc.url and other similar properties. But where can I specify this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SessionCustomizer to set the JDBC property on your Session's DatabaseLogin.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL, simply append the args as a parameter in the url as in the example below:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demandas_gs?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```